# INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113 device

Tags: android

When I execute my android project in android 8.0 device.I get the error "INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113"

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kbHc.png)

But when I execute in android 7.0 is normal.

After I check,I find

```
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
```

cause the error.

Like this image.
[error image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8tb9.png)

Is it because the signalr jar version too old?

note:I do not use AVD. I use real device.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all, substitute the official files of SignalR SDK with the files that you can find at this link:
https://github.com/eak65/FixedSignalRJar

When you do that, edit the "build.gradle" file of your application, adding the following code in the "android" block, after the "buildTypes" block:

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }

packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/getLibs.ps1'
        exclude 'lib/getLibs.sh'
        exclude 'lib/gson-2.2.2.jar'
    }
```

The above solution helped me after a lot of struggling!
I hope it helps you too!

Comment: I'm happy to have been of help!

Comment: Hey man, thank you so much! After several hours of investigations, wtfs and after a lot of struggling this was the key point. Btw, it works for me without the fixed SignalR jars.

Comment: @pr0gg3r thank you for your note. In my case the use of fixed JARs was still essential. Happy to have given you a hand!

Comment: Thank you so much for this. But can you also explain the problem we all were facing ?!

Comment: trust Microsoft, they said ... it will be fun they said!

Comment: `signalr-client-sdk.jar` is the main problem, not `signalr-client-sdk-android.jar`