# AngularJS and ASP.NET Core SignalR

Tags: android, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core, signalr

I am developing a chat on an old project that has a front end using AngularJS, a mobile app using Android (Java 1.7) and a back end using ASP.NET. I researched and decided to use SignalR because of it being free and adequate to the requirements that were given.

Unfortunately, I came across the following problem:
I successfully implemented the communciation between the hub in ASP.NET (Not Core) and the platform, but in Android, the libraries for ASP.NET were very hard to find and the ones that i found were deprecated. To fix this, i used instead the ASP.NET Core library in the mobile app, updated it to java 1.8 and created a microservice using ASP.NET Core only for the signalr because the backend used ASP.NET (Not Core), which worked fine and seemed to even be a greater solution considering that it could be reused for any other current and future projects.

Now, I supposedly just had to update the AngularJS code to use the new signalr hub in ASP.NET Core but the library is written in typescript and i can't find any documentation on how to implement it using AngularJS...

To simplify, the problem is:

AngularJS (1.*) <--> ASP.NET works but Android <--> ASP.NET doesn't.

Android <--> ASP.NET Core works but AngularJS (1.*) <--> ASP.NET Core doesn't

Is it possible to use a typescript library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/signalr) in AngularJS or, at the very least, use the ASP.NET Signalr in Java?

EDIT:

Resolved in
[INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614853/install-failed-no-matching-abis-failed-to-extract-native-libraries-res-113-de)

Comment: The Java client supports connecting to the ASP.NET Core SignalR server from Java code (including Android applications), refer to the official documentation:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: With all due respect, i clearly specified i could make it work for Android <--> ASP.NET Core, but couldn't for AngularJS (1.*) <--> ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Have you succeeded in making it work? Currently trying to achieve the same

Comment: Yes indeed, i had a lot of struggle but eventually fixed by doing what i mentioned above (after "Edit").